# Android 13: Xamarin.Forms doesn't give permissions to access gallery images

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, permissions

since Android 13, my Xamarin.Forms app no longer has the required permissions to access the images in the gallery. I know that Google has changed the access conditions and that we need to replace READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE with Granular media permissions: READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO and READ_MEDIA_AUDIO.
I've applied all these changes, but access to the images is still denied (I don't have a permission request from the system). Worse, when I manually assign permissions myself, it doesn't work either. Finally, it seems that the Xamarin.Essentials component (I'm on version 1.8.0) doesn't consider the changes imposed by Android 13. Is there an update planned? Is there a way around this?
Here's my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.ApriSoft.memocourses" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="5.0.3" android:versionCode="503">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
<application android:label="MemoCourses.Android">
    <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="msauth" android:host="com.ApriSoft.memocourses" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
```

And the MainActivity.cs file:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static MemoCourses.Droid.MainActivity;
using Android.Content;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using MemoCourses.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Android.Text.Method;
using Android.Text;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadMediaImages)]/* CSS Document*/

namespace MemoCourses.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "MemoCourses", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());
            App.AuthUIParent = this;
            Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(255, 47, 56, 40));
            ButtonCircleRenderer.Init();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to choose the image:

```
try
{
    FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
    //
    var filepath = fileData.FilePath;
    //
    if (fileData == null)
        return; // user canceled file picking
    
    newimageByte = fileData.DataArray;
    resizedImageByte = await ImageResizer.ResizeImage(newimageByte, 200, 200);

    if (resizedImageByte != null)
    {
        var stream1 = new MemoryStream(resizedImageByte);
        ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    
    imageGallery = false;
    imageChanged = false;
}
```

Thank you very much for helping me, I've been looking for several days, and I can't find a solution. All users of my app whose phone has been updated to Android 13 can no longer pick an image from the gallery.

Comment: `app no longer has the required permissions to access the images in the gallery.` Dont know what you consider 'the gallery'on an Android device. But using the normal Android image or file pickers one never needed any permission to do so. Nor for accessing the files with the obtained uries.

Comment: `can no longer upload an image` Upload? That is step three. First comes picking and  opening.

Comment: @blackapps I think you don't know Xamarin.forms or even Andoid very well because the term Gallery is the one that is officially used on all Android phones to designate the location where all images are stored. And I'm not the only one to raise this problem...

Comment: Images on an Android device can be stored all over the place. And there can be a an app named Gallery. And there is no location where all images are stored and there is no Gallery. Anyhow no permissions needed. You did not react on that. Although it was your problem.

Comment: I may have expressed myself wrong, but check out this link (https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the method on my side and it worked well. You can use the codes below to upload the pictures on Android 13. Please put the code in the `MainActivity` class.

```
   public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
            {
                if (Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 13 && (permissions.Where(p => p.Equals("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")).Any() || permissions.Where(p => p.Equals("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")).Any()))
                {
                    var wIdx = Array.IndexOf(permissions, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
                    var rIdx = Array.IndexOf(permissions, "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
    
                    if (wIdx != -1 && wIdx < permissions.Length) grantResults[wIdx] = Permission.Granted;
                    if (rIdx != -1 && rIdx < permissions.Length) grantResults[rIdx] = Permission.Granted;
                }
    
                Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
```

---

I made a demo, and you can try to use this to get the image form the photo by using the Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker.

Here is the code in Mainpage.xaml.

```
 <Image x:Name="FotoProduto"></Image>
 <Button x:Name="button" Text="button" Clicked="button_Clicked"></Button>
```

The code in the Mainpage.xaml.cs.

```
private async void button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Choise the product photo"
            });

            var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

            FotoProduto.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);


        }
```

Update method in Mainpage.xaml.cs

Do not use the stream way.

```
  var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Choise the product photo"
            });
            var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, result.FileName);

            FotoProduto.Source = newFile;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately, I added the code that you gave me to the MainActivity.cs file and it does not work. I added in the question the portion of code that I use to choose the image. This is where access is denied. Perhaps the CrossFilePicker command is causing the problem?

Comment: `CrossFilePicker` has not been supported anymore. You can use the [Xamarin.Essentials: Media Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) to pick the image in the photos or gallery.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide the code and you can use it to get the photo.

Comment: Thanks again, but now I have another problem: on this line of code `var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();` the stream is correct (CanRead = true CanWrite = false Length = 2237991), but the next line gives me the error `Length = System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object`. and also `Object name: 'Stream has been closed'. System.ArgumentNullException: 'Buffer cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer'`. Why ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use these codes instead of using the stream.  `var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Choise the product photo"
            });
            var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, result.FileName);

            FotoProduto.Source = newFile;`

Comment: You can check the answer I updated.

Comment: I made the changes you told me, but I still get the same error message after the line of code `FotoProduto.Source = newFile;` (System.ArgumentNullException: 'Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer').

Comment: Important information: I created a new application xamarin.forms and applied your changes: everything works correctly. The buffer error comes from somewhere else in the code, but where? I'll look it up, but I think you've answered my initial question. Thank you so much !

Comment: This work for me. Must include Package [Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions)